# SSIS Package failed to decrypt a column encryption key when run from SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: encryption, ssis, jobs, sql-server-agent

In our SSIS package we are inserting data from a third party database with some encrypted columns and for that we install a certificate in our SQL server Managed Instance.

The Problem is when we run a package manually, the data is decrypting and the SSIS package is running successfully but when we deploy the package to SSISDB catalogs and run it from the SQL Server Agent Job we are getting a "failed to decrypt a column encryption store using key store provider MSSQL_Certificate_Store".

Comment: Where is the sql server agent running from?  Is this on a different VM or is it part of the managed instance?  If it's part of the managed instance, then are the packages running using the ADF runtime?

Comment: Everything is from the same VM. we have  visual studio installed in our VM and we are running packages from there and we also have some jobs scheduled from SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Make sure that the account that is running SQL agent has permissions to the certificate on the server.  Sometimes these are installed under a specific user account by mistake instead of for the whole machine

Comment: Mark can u please advice me on how to check the SQL agent permissions to access the certificate? We ran the certificate wizard on our Server by selecting the  local machine and we are currently using admin_wr login to connect to the database engine and even the Agent is using the same login and the SQL Server is using NTService account. i couldn't really connect the dots here.

Answer (score 0):

To add permissions to the certificate:

1. On the server, go to Manage Computer Certificates
2. Find the certificate.  The user that added it can find it under personal.
3. Right click, All Tasks, Manage Private Keys...

[image]

4. Add the user in the permissions dialogue:

[image]

Comment: admin user is already there but  normally do we need to add the user with the domain name or anything is ok. because in the below screen the admin user is like WVRMSQL1\administrator https://ibb.co/9ZtZnc8

Comment: It's the `admin_wr` account that is running the sql agent service that you need to add if the ssis package is running under the sql agent account.  If it's running under a proxy, the proxy account needs to be added.